# I want to get OrderID from API responce using cy.intercept in cypress

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, web-api-testing

I want to get the order ID from the API response. When I click on the Create Order button it will send a POST API request and return the ID that I want to save in my JSON file.

This is my order creation code.

```
cy.clickOnElement(practicePageSelectors.CreateOrder).click(); // click on add Rx button
cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/Data.json').then((profile) => {
   cy.searchPatients(practicePageSelectors.searchPatient1, profile.Patient_fullName);
})
cy.searchDoctors(); // search for the doctor
cy.clickOnElementUsingXpath(practicePageSelectors.nextButtonId); // click on the next button
cy.clickOnElement(practicePageSelectors.createOnetimeOrder)
cy.searchMedicine() //search for Medicine
cy.clickOnElementUsingXpathfirst(practicePageSelectors.addMedicine); // click on add button
cy.clickOnElementUsingText(practiceData.paymentButtonName, practiceData.buttonTag); // click on skip payment button
cy.clickOnElementUsingXpath(practicePageSelectors.submit_CreateOrderButton)
```

And I tried something like this

```
cy.intercept({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://ibis-dev.droicelabs.us/api/dispenser/orders/',
    }).then((responce)=>{
      let body = JSON.parse(responce.body)
      cy.log(body)
    })
```

I don't know how to use `intercept`. Please guide me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to register the interceptor before the http call will be made and then wait for the data within your test.

This should happen either in `before` hook or on top of your actual test case.

```js
cy.intercept({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://ibis-dev.droicelabs.us/api/dispenser/orders/',
}).as('ordersCall')
```

and then in place where you will need the ID

```js
cy.wait('@ordersCall')
  .its('response.body')
  .then((body) => {
    // parsing might be not needed always, depends on the api response
    const bodyData = JSON.parse(body) 
    cy.log(bodyData)
  })
```

Side note: `cy.fixture()` reads directly from `fixtures` directory - no need to use `cy.readFile`

Comment: Thank you for your response. But It will through the error `Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: ordersCall. No request ever occurred` in `cy.wait('@ordersCall')` line.

Comment: In my case I could directly do `.its('response.body.id')`