# Keep old data in JSON file and write API response in JSON file

Tags: cypress, writefile

I am writing JSON file like this way

```
cy.readFile("cypress/fixtures/Data.json").then((profile) => {
    profile.OrderID = bodyData
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/Data.json', profile)
})
```

In my JSON file, data would be written like this
[image]

I have tried

```
cy.readFile("cypress/fixtures/Data.json").then((profile) => {
    profile = bodyData
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/Data.json', profile)
})
```

But it will remove my other data write a file like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an existing JSON file you want to append data to, I would recommend using `cy.writeFile` as follows:

```js
cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/Data.json', profile, {flag: a+})
```

You can find details regarding the usage of the `flag: a+` and additional options [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile#Flags) in the Cypress Docs.

In case you want the OrderID to just contain the Id "61e909ba076c2a6257ddd909", you can do the following adjustment additionally:

```js
cy.readFile("cypress/fixtures/Data.json").then((profile) => {
    profile.OrderID = bodyData._id
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/Data.json', profile)
})
```

Comment: `cy.log(bodyData._id)` is not return anything Please check the image [https://ibb.co/3hsMZj5]

Comment: The assumption was that bodyData is a JSON object containing only the key "_id". You could also try bodyData['_id']. In case it is not parsed at that point in your code, you might need to add JSON.parse before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either lodash `defaultsDeep()` method to recursively assigns properties or the spread operator, like:

```
cy.readFile("cypress/fixtures/Data.json").then((profile) => {
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/Data.json', {...profile, ...bodyData})
})
```